# How to wake up Android on touch (not with use power button)?

Tags: android

How to wake up Android with touch of screen not power button?

I found that PowerManager with AccessibilityService could be used but maybe there is more trivial solution.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> How to wake up Android with touch of screen not power button?

This is not possible.

> I found that PowerManager with AccessibilityService could be used

No, it cannot. Presumably with reference to `PowerManager`, you mean using a `WakeLock`, in which case the device is not asleep, by definition.

Comment: Thanks for hits. It looks that Android is bound more to phone than tables. I think about application fo 4.0.3 that off/on screen on touch no mean full wake up (Android is _on standby_) so one click on power bring screen at once without booting. This will be used on terminals not phones. I saw that Android 4.2 will have screen saver but not found solution for 4.0.3.

Answer (score 2):

If your device have proximity sensor you can install service that will wakeup screen by touching proximity sensor. Simple search for "wakeup, proximity" words in Google Play.

Comment: That is good idea if there is proximity sensor - I should test it thx for hint - whatever I think it is rare so currently only method is power button.

Answer (score 0):

depends on your phone - the infuse 4g has just got this introduced under cm10.1